# Create a UINavigationController iOS app without using storyboards with Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios-4.2, xcode4.3

I want to create an app for iPod Touch 2nd generation (iOS 4.2.1). For this target OS storyboards cannot be used. I want to use UINavigationControllers to manage several views.
I've seen several tutorials on how to do this starting from a window-based app template but I don't have that project template on Xcode 4.3.2. Could anyone give me some hints on how to proceed with this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_5_iPhone_Application_using_TableViews

It'll show you how to start with an empty project.

Hope that helps.